# Alphabetically order in group_concat

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

i have a table CITY which have column Name

'Noida'
'Delhi'
'Lahor'
'Bagdad'
'New York'
'Bangkok'
'Londan'
'Dubai'
'Islamabad'
'Columbo'

through Group_concat i want that all city name come in alphabetically order in different rows as like given below

'Bagdad,Bangkok'
'Columbo'
'Delhi,Dubai'
'Islamabad'
'Lahor,Londan'
'New York,Noida'

Comment: ... and what you've tried so far is...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are looking for the `order by` clause in `group_concat()` along with aggregation by the first letter in the string:

```
select group_concat(name order by name)
from cities
group by left(name, 1)
order by left(name, 1);
```